# Unable to import default Business Application kjar project into Business Central

Tags: jbpm

I am following the documentation provided in https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.33.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/. Section 3.7.6.3, `Import your business assets project into Business Central`. On following the steps to import the project I am getting the following error in Business Central `There are no projects available to import. Check the URL, the credentials, and if there's a master branch in the repository.`
I have also read https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3455191 but am still getting the same error.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have you been able to resolve it?